# Search form doesn't work on front end database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I split a database and created a search form in the front end. It works there, but when I copy the front end, the search form doesn't work there

The form is a continuous form and has my table as a datasource. There are a number of bound fields in the detail section and a number of unbound fields in the form header. On the click of the search button, I use vba to build a sql select string and use Me.RecordSource = strSQL. Again this works in my original front end db. After realizing it doesn't work in a copy, I have tried copying and pasting the form from one front end to another, export/import, recreating it, hard coding a select, trying to display a message box on the click...nothing seems to work on the button click (tried double click too). If I build a button with the wizard, it will work, but they are using built in macros.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If no code seems to run in your new database (including MsgBox), then it is quite likely that the new database is in a folder that Access doesn't recognize as "trustworthy" and has therefore turned off code running.

Check that the folder where the database is currently located is allowed to run code, and if not add the folder:

File|Options|Trust Center|Trust Center Settings|Trusted Locations

Regards,